# Need help on PHP

Tags: php

I want to pass the quantity to another page but im not using a form. How could i do this?

```
<input type='text' id='quantity' name='quantity' />
<a href='Cart.php?code=$productCode'><input type='button' id='addCart' name='addCart' value='Add Cart' /><hr>
```

Anything wrong with this code? Am trying to use jquery to pass the quantity on a link and assign back to the link button

```
<input type='text' id='quantity' name='quantity' />
<a href='Cart.php?id=$user_id&code=$productCode'><input type='button' id='addCart' name='addCart' value='Add Cart' /></a>
<hr>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#quantity').keyup(function () {
         var quantity = $(this).val();
         var link = 'Cart.php?code=$productCode&quantity=' + quantity;
         $('#addCart').attr('href', link);
    });
</script>";
```

Comment: Do you need help with PHP or jQuery?

Comment: It's also not necessary to have a button inside the HREF as either can do the job of submitting your data for processing.

Comment: is html being `echoed` out by PHP or something? You can't just stuff `$whatever` into html and expect those variables to magically get replaced with values.

Comment: If you want to pass something from the page to some PHP use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 3):

It is not valid to have a `<button>` inside an `<a href>`.

Consider using CSS to make your link look like a button, *or* use jQuery to listen to `click` on the button and go to the `link` when it is clicked.

That said, a form would be much easier:

```
<form action="Cart.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="$userid" />
    <input type="hidden" name="code" value="$productCode" />
    <input type="number" name="quantity" value="1" />
    <button type="submit" name="addCart">Add Cart</button>
</form>
```

No jQuery needed.

Comment: This is my code

$outputList = ''; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ $productID = $row['PRODUCT_ID']; $productCode = $row['PRODUCT_CODE']; $productName = $row['PRODUCT_NAME']; $productDesc = $row['PRODUCT_DESC']; $productBrandName = $row['PRODUCT_BRAND_NAME']; $productCategoryName = $row['PRODUCT_CATEGORY_NAME']; $priceNormal = $row['PRICE_NORMAL']; $pricePromo = $row['PRICE_PROMO']; $outOfStock = $row['IS_OUT_OF_STOCK'];

Comment: $outputList .= " <table><tr><td>"."<img src='Includes/Images/uploads/".$row['PRODUCT_IMAGE']."' width='150px' height='150px'></img>"."</td></tr> <tr><td><b>Product code : </b></td><td>$productCode</td><tr/> <tr><td><b>Product name : </b></td><td>$productName</td><tr/> <tr><td><b>Product description : </b></td><td>$productDesc</td><tr/> <tr><td><b>Product brand : </b></td><td>$productBrandName</td><tr/> <tr><td><b>Product category : </b></td><td>$productCategoryName</td><tr/>

Comment: <tr><td><b>Normal Price : </b></td><td>$priceNormal</td><tr/> <tr><td><b>Promotion Price : </b></td><td>$pricePromo</td><tr/> <tr><td><b>Date Start : </b></td><td>$dateStart</td></tr> <tr><td><b>Date End : </b></td><td>$dateEnd</td></tr> <tr><td><input type='text' id='quantity' name='quantity'/> <a href='Cart.php?code=$productCode'> <input type='button' id='addCart' name='addCart' value='Add Cart' /></a></td></tr></table><hr>"; }

When i enter quantity on the selected product, i click add cart, and then the quantity will be pass to another php. How could i do this?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to pass the quantity to another page but im not using a form. How could i do this?

Simplest solution: use a form. That's what they're there for. You already have a field and a button, just put a form tag around it. No need to overcomplicate.

Comment: @belltric So what? You can have more than one form on a page.

Comment: @belltric Your code is in a `while` loop, yet you have `id` attributes. Result: duplicate IDs, and non-functional code.

Comment: my code

 $outputList = '';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 

        $productID = $row['PRODUCT_ID'];
        $productCode = $row['PRODUCT_CODE'];
        $productName = $row['PRODUCT_NAME'];
        $productDesc = $row['PRODUCT_DESC'];
        $productBrandName = $row['PRODUCT_BRAND_NAME'];
        $productCategoryName = $row['PRODUCT_CATEGORY_NAME'];
        $priceNormal = $row['PRICE_NORMAL'];
        $pricePromo = $row['PRICE_PROMO'];
        
        $outOfStock = $row['IS_OUT_OF_STOCK'];

Comment: $outputList .= "   
<table><tr><td>"."<img src='Includes/Images/uploads/".$row['PRODUCT_IMAGE']."' width='150px' height='150px'></img>"."</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Product code : </b></td><td>$productCode</td><tr/>
<tr><td><b>Product name : </b></td><td>$productName</td><tr/>   
<tr><td><b>Product description : </b></td><td>$productDesc</td><tr/> 
<tr><td><b>Product brand : </b></td><td>$productBrandName</td><tr/> 
<tr><td><b>Product category : </b></td><td>$productCategoryName</td><tr/>

Comment: <tr><td><b>Normal Price : </b></td><td>$priceNormal</td><tr/>
<tr><td><b>Promotion Price : </b></td><td>$pricePromo</td><tr/>
<tr><td><b>Date Start : </b></td><td>$dateStart</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Date End : </b></td><td>$dateEnd</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type='text' id='quantity' name='quantity'/>
<a href='Cart.php?code=$productCode'>
<input type='button' id='addCart' name='addCart' value='Add Cart' /></a></td></tr></table><hr>";
}

Comment: When i enter quantity on the selected product, i click add cart, and then the quantity will be pass to another php. How could i do this?

Comment: Basic PHP. Stop posting giant blocks of code as comments.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('#quantity').keyup(function(event) {
    var quantity = $(this).val();
    var url_act = $('a#puls').attr('href');
    var new_link = url_act+'&quantity='+quantity;
    $('a#puls').removeAttr('href').attr('href', new_link);
});
```

```html
<input type='text' id='quantity' name='quantity' />
<a href='Cart.php?id=$user_id&code=$productCode' id='puls'>Add Cart</a>
```

Use this with jQuery...is the answer to your first question

Comment: This will result in links like `Cart.php?id=1&code=2&quantity=1&quantity=12&quantity=128&quantity=1283`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol My answer would be valid only if at first place; as you have pointed out, then will be linked back to the variable quantity unless it is carried out the question correctly in order to better understand the problem ;)

Comment: i wan a link button instead of link. 
I enter quantity and then i click on the link button.
After that, i wan to add the quantity into the link and pass to another page